# How to avoid multiple request with SOAP API and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, soap, knockout.js

I currently have an application that calls my laravel backend on a mouse click. The laravel application further makes a SOAP request to the endpoint. This returns a JSON object. We then pass this returned JSON data to the front end.

Everything in this application seems to be working as anticipated, however, of late we have realised that we have been making more than 50 requests at a time while making the SOAP request. This is bad and I was wondering if I could get any help to rectify this issue.

I am currently running
laravel 5 with PHP 5.4.
Front-end is based on knockout within squiz matrix.
SOAP request has a timestamp of 60 seconds as a mandatory parameter

Comment: Is the data cacheable? that's probably where you need to start. You'd probably also want the cache to refresh from one hit and not 50 concurrent requests (aka stale cache serving).

Comment: hello, Scuzzy I am not sure if I understand the stale cache serving concept well enough. My application doesn't need to work along with cached data. All I know is we have a few mandatory parameters that we will have to pass in my SOAP request to get back a response. Amongst which 60 seconds timestamp is a must.

Comment: I was thinking about what happens if two people tried to refresh the data at the same time, one approach is to always keep a "old" copy of the data and serve untill it's refreshed by just a single request or a background process.

I think it just depends on how time sensitive your data is.

Comment: you click once and it makes 50 requests ? sound weird

Comment: hello John yes it is very weird and I can't wait to rectify this issue. It could either be the SOAP request if not it could also be something related to knockout js. the button function that makes the API call to the laravel application is written in knockout js. part of me also thinks it could be a front end issue.

Comment: Hello @Scuzzy the application will require different value from different user. the soap request returns a reference number and the price for the product they wish to purchase.